# Critical Edition and multiple footnotes

Tags: footnotes, reledmac

Hi and first of all sorry if I'm asking (stupid) questions being asked several times before.

I'm about to make a critical edition with reledmac. Its a Greek-German edition (original text and translation on facing pages) with some tricky footnote stuff:

First, there has to be an apparatus, which appears on both sides, with "numbering" from a,..,z,aa,...zz,.... This apparatus has to restart after each pair of facing pages. It has to be mentioned only on the left (Greek) side with the Greek version.

Then there is a critical apparatus, also only on the side with the Greek version.

Last but not least, there has to be an apparatus with footnotes, starting from 1,...,999. The footnotes have to be in both versions of the text, original and translation. The footnote-text has to be a continuing one over both pages.

So my main problem is how to set up the notes and modify them to make it possible to change their style from line numbers to numbers and single letters.

I would be very grateful if someone of you can help me (total super-noob) and Thanks in advance!

Comment: he, mara? could validate the answer, if OK?

Answer (score 4):

You ask for many questions in the same question, which all of these answer are detailled on the handbook and in the example joined https://ctan.org/pkg/reledmac.

Here a MWE of facing page

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage{libertineotf}
\setmainlanguage{english}


\usepackage[series={A},noend,noeledsec,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}


\begin{document}

\date{}
\title{Parallel}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This file provides two minimal examples of typesetting parallel texts with reledmac plus reledpar. 

The first minimal example is parallel typesetting in columns, the second one is parallel typesetting in pages.
\end{abstract}


\begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}

\end{pages} 
\Pages

\end{document}
```

If you want to restart lineation at each page, use

```
\lineation*{page}
```

To make a critical footnote, do

```
\edtext{lemma}{\Afootnote{text of the critical footnote}}
```

To make a familiar footnote, without lemma but with a footnotemark, do

```
text\footnoteA{texte of the footnote}
```

As you use familiar footnote on both side, you should do multiple run to get the correct number. In general, with reledmac/reledpar, it is better to use tools like latexmk wich automatically does multiple runs for you.

But, in general, it is also better to read the handbook…

Answer (score 0):

Maïeul wrote a book in French, which includes the following advice in Chapter 20, translated to English per Google translate:

“We will address here two packages particularly useful in human sciences: ledmac to make critical editions and ledpar (which can not be used separately from ledmac) to edit a text and its translation in parallel. These packages contain a lot of features: here we present only a few and refer to manuals for others.”

http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/info/latex-sciences-humaines.pdf

“Note also that reledmac is the successor to eledmac, which was the successor to ledmac (and similarly with reledpar); only the re-* packages are currently maintained. There is no good reason to start a project today that uses ledmac instead of reledmac.” – jon Oct 15 '17 at 17:24

Comment: A translation to English is needed.

Comment: Note also that `reledmac` is the successor to `eledmac`, which was the successor to `ledmac` (and similarly with `reledpar`); only the re-* packages are currently maintained. There is no good reason to start a project today that uses `ledmac` instead of `reledmac`.